# Flux.mergeDelayError get all errors

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive

When using mergeDelayError of Reactor, if more than 1 error is being emitted, is there a way to get all of them instead of just the first error?

```
Flux.mergeDelayError(10,
                     Flux.fromStream(Stream.of(1, 2, 3))
                         .flatMap(i -> Mono.error(new Exception(i.toString()))),
                     Mono.just(1),
                     Mono.just(2))
    .doOnError(error -> log.error("error, {}", error.getMessage()))
    .collectList()
    .flatMap(Mono::just) .block();
```

In the example above, it only prints `error 1` and exits without printing `error 2`, `error 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that is not possible. Please note that any error in a reactive stream is considered a terminal event. So, when your flux returned a first error, it terminates without actually proceeding any further. **DelayError** will only wait for other publishers to terminate (with success or error).

Also, note that if multiple publishers throw their individual exception, the reactor would throw special **CompositeException** which wraps the exceptions thrown by the individual publisher.